# Appear/Add/Leave animations on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to animate a widget (or a list of widget) depending on it's life cycle.
Something that allows to have an animation when the widget appears for the first time on screen ; when it's edited ; and when it leaves the screen.

While I know how to do it manually, it seems to requires a bit too much work. 
So the question here is : Is there in flutter an easy way to do this ? Something similar to ReactCSSTransitionGroup from react but in flutter maybe ?

I know that there's AnimatedList widget. But you have to manually trigger add/remove animations by accessing to the AnimatedListState, which is a pain.

Comment: Can't you use ```initState()``` and ```dispose()``` for creation and destruction? But dispose is probably to late, isn't it?

Comment: Actually not it's not late. I know it you how to do it manually. But it's a hell lot of work for what it is. The question is weither there is or not a widget that does the work for you (Most likely using `key`). The desired result is to be as close as `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` as possible.

Comment: Does [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_villains) package do what you want?